"Gods" create cold-blooded humanoids who lay eggs in a fire cave
This is a short story written before 1995.
The main characters are two beings referred to as the "gods".
They arrive on an uninhabited planet and design a race to live there. They make them cold-blooded to save energy, and give them an inbuilt fear of fire to stop them repeating the mistakes the gods had made. They make a volcanically-heated cave which I think the creatures refer to as the "fire cave". Every autumn, the creatures lay eggs and store them in the fire cave, then they go back to their dwellings and die during the winter. The gods hear them praying for help as the weather worsens, but they let them die.
Next spring, the eggs hatch out and the new generation have to learn about their world. Their only help is cave-paintings left by previous generations to tell them about useful plants or inventions.
Eventually, one of the creatures figures out that they can overwinter inside the fire cave, and persuades the others to do the same. I think they have to overcome their fear of fire to do so.
Once the gods see that their creations are going to survive the winter, they consider their work done and quietly leave the planet.

You had me at the question's title! :)

yes, intriguing. but i have never bought the star trekian (and seen elsewhere) idea that a species would feel compelled to seed other planets with life.

@releseabe - What species? I only see two individuals. Or do you mean that you find it implausible that that there could exist two individuals with that motivation in the whole universe?
